# Java-Maven-IntelliJ: How to define a "portable" JDK that is bundled with the project as the SDK/JRE to compile and run?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, sdk, jvm

UPDATE: Looks like it's not possible yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240044
I'll update the question with an answer, once this issue is resolved (this way or the other)

I have a super-special version of the JDK customized to compile and run a desktop client I am providing as an IntelliJ project (with source).

Users of my client can't get it to work with the Java they have installed on their work stations by our corporate IT.
On the other hand, they need that standard Java to run other things. The custom JDK is not good for running the other Java applications our corporate requires (so, I can't just have my JDK as their system-wide JDK).

Also, the work stations of my users do not support containerization.

So, I am thinking to bundle my JDK with the project and configure it to use that SDK. This is going beyond just preparing a "setEnv.bat" script with "JAVA_HOME=/xjdk" for many reasons, like being able to debug using the IDE, when the IDE is debugging code compiled with the special JDK...

I know IntelliJ has places to set up the JDK and JRE but not sure how to do this in a "relative path" way and such that will run on both Mac/Win without them having to configure the project for the absolute path of the bundled JDK?

Assume the project structure is something like this:
ProjectFolder
 |_ src
 |_ xJDK

What IntelliJ/Maven elements do I need to set to get both compile and run using xJDK?